# How to URL Decode in Power Apps Portals

Tags: liquid, powerapps-portal

Is there similar functionality to Shopify's  [url_decode](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/url_decode/) in Power Apps Portal using Liquid. I tried using the filter mentioned in the link above but doesn't work with Power Apps Portal.

I'm trying to get "Serivces & Fees" from "?ParentCategory=Services%20&%20Fees&SubCategory=Test".

Comment: Is the string part of the page url?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Liquid filter that respond to you need, here the example: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/url_decode/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @B. Irena, but the Shopify liquid filter does not work with the Power Apps Portal liquid tag.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is part of the page url you can use liquid

```
{% assign ParentCategory = request.params['ParentCategory'] %}
```

Usage:

```
<a href={{ rParentCategory }}>Link</a>
```